# Problem in adding jQuery code to open and close the shipping form box

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I display the billing form and the shipping form on order-pay page, I want the check box of the shipping form to open and close like the checkout page, That's why I use the following code:

```
<script>
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    var wc_order_review_form = {
        $order_review: $( '#order_review' ),
        init: function() {
            this.$order_review.on( 'change', '#ship-to-different-address input', this.ship_to_different_address );
            this.$order_review.find( '#ship-to-different-address input' ).trigger( 'change' );
        },
        ship_to_different_address: function() {
            $( 'div.shipping_address' ).hide();
            if ( $( this ).is( ':checked' ) ) {
                $( 'div.shipping_address' ).slideDown();
            }
        },
    };
    wc_order_review_form.init();
} );
</script>
```

But there is a problem: the shipping state field that has a drop-down list, Its span tag is not added :

```
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: 100%;"><span class="selection">
...
</span>
```

If I remove the following code, this problem is no longer there, but by default the window is open even though it is not checked

```
this.$order_review.find( '#ship-to-different-address input' ).trigger( 'change' );
```